# Проблемы со связкой Apache+PHP+MySQL  под Win7 x64

Tags: веб-программирование, веб-сервер

Доброго времени суток.
Возникла задача поставить веб сервер под WIN 7 x64.
Установлено:
-2.2.14 (Win32)
-PHP 5.2.4
-Mysql server 5,5(х64)

Всё настроено и работает, но PHP  не работает с Mysql.
Ошибка " Call to undefined function mysql_connect()";
Пути к модулям прописаны верно.
Всё что надо раскоментировано.
Но phpinfo даже секции про Mysql  нет.
По гуглил, толкового ниче не нашел. 
Может кто сталкивался с подобным? кто что подскажет?

Comment: а сам модуль присутствует в папке .\ext ?
[PHP_MYSQL]
extension=php_mysql.dll

Comment: да, конечно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотри по этой ссылке инфу: [Подключение к PHP расширения для работы с MySQL](http://www.softtime.ru/article/index.php?id_article=98)

Comment: я же объяснил, все модули подключены.

Comment: смотри там раздел: "Нет блока MySQL в phpinfo()"